# How to change the view mode programmatically?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I want to change the view mode of node programmatically. I used `hook_preprocess_node(&$vars)` and set the view mode:

```
function moduleName_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
      // if conditions to apply particular view mode
      $vars['view_mode'] = 'teaser';
      $vars['elements']['#view_mode'] = 'teaser';
}
```

But this is not working as expected. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you try reviewing this? http://drupal.org/node/1334206

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Altering the view mode in the preprocess function is doing it too late.
The correct way to alter the view module is implementing [hook_entity_view_mode_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7), which is called before the entity content is rendered. For example, in [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7), that hook is invoked from [node_build_content()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_build_content/7), which is the first function called from `node_view()`.

```
  if (!isset($langcode)) {
    $langcode = $GLOBALS['language_content']->language;
  }

  // Populate $node->content with a render() array.
  node_build_content($node, $view_mode, $langcode);
```

Comment: Thank you. Please note that this hook requires drupal >= 7.17

Answer (score 6):

If you need to just change it for certain pages, I'd suggest [View Mode Page](http://drupal.org/project/view_mode_page). It's pretty handy and simple to use.

Comment: Thank you. But I do have different scenario. I want to use different view mode for nodes with same content type. I want to alter the view mode on the taxonomy I used in the node. I mean the nodes will have same URL patterns.