# A content type with two or more view displays with custom URLs

Tags: path-aliases

I have a content type that requires different views.  I am defining multiple view modes in the content type manage display page and using view page mode.  This works fine if the url is /%/{view mode} as defined in the view page module.  However, we would like the view's url alias to be a custom alias.

Default view alias:  /subpath/[node:title] (Pathauto pattern) 
View 1: /%/myview which translates to /subpath/[node:title]/myview  (View Page Mode)

We'd like /%/myview to have its own alias like /mysubpath/[node:title] .

From what I understand, Pathauto alias works only with default views.  How can I make this happen?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59690/how-to-change-the-view-mode-programmatically. I bet you can either choose a view mode based on the URL, or maybe the module mentioned there will help you.

Comment: I think the problem is related to canonical urls.  
I have two aliases for same nodeId:

/subpath/{arg} -> /node/{nodeId}  
/second-subpath/{arg} -> /node/{nodeId}/online  
Where /node/{nodeId}/online is defined in ViewMode Page as /%/online.  

By the time the hook_entity_view_mode_alter is reached, the url alias for the alternative view mode has already thrown a 404.  The view mode does indeed get changed, but the page has already thrown the 404.  In the URL alias,

Comment: Sounds to me then that what you really need is to get the two URLS to point to the same node. Put the View mode aside for a bit. Once you know that that works, you can use `hook_entity_view_mode_alter` to key off the request URL to pick a view mode for the node..